# IOS: save an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, object, nsmutablearray, plist, nsuserdefaults

I want to save an array of object when I close my app, now I use NSUserDefault in this way:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData* myClassArrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appDelegate.favorite];
    [defaults setObject:myClassArrayData forKey:@"favorite"];
```

but I want to know if there are other methods to save this array (example: plist file ecc...)

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's wrong with `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: I have some problem when I delete a row in a tableview...

Comment: So why don't you ask about your problem rather than something you hope might be a potential solution?

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSData` for simple methods to read and write the `NSData` object from/to a file.

Comment: There are two reasonably robust & general mechanisms:  [Property lists](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1) and [JSON](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You need to implement initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder.
To save to file, just do :

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray toFile:@"someFile"];
```

to load it:

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"someFile"];
```

Comment: I know but i have this problem and my question ask other methods to save an array